# Temporary failure in name resolution on creating a doctrine database

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, doctrine, symfony5

I create a new project as I did several times.
But this time, I have problems to create the doctrine database.

I tried with an existing database and without
Adminer, is also able to connect mysql and work with the database

Any hints for me?
Regards,
n00n

The failures:

```
In ExceptionConverter.php line 98:
                                                                                                                                                  
  An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution  
                                                                                                                                                  

In Exception.php line 26:
                                                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution  
                                                                                                             

In Connection.php line 34:
                                                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution  
                                                                                                             

In Connection.php line 34:
                                                                                                          
  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

My Symfony Database link in .env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:pass@db:3306/webdb?serverVersion=5.7
```

My Dockerfile
version: "3.3"

```
services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: r00t
      MYSQL_DATABASE: webdb
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'pass'

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15.3-alpine
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - "./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro"
      - "./application:/usr/src/app"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    volumes:
      - "./application:/usr/src/app"
      - "./temporary/composer/cache:/.composer/cache"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env
    user: 1000:1000
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=192.168.178.41 remote_timeout=30
    links:
      - db
```